# performing backend operations / tasks after specific intervals of time on Google App Engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks, backend, task-queue

I want my GAE app to do some back-end processing and uploading/updating results to data-store after specific intervals of time (say every 6 hours). So whenever a user uses my app (and basically requests those values from the data-store) they would get the recent/updated values from the data-store.

How would this be implemented in google app engine? I'd really appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction and/or provide me with information pertinent to doing something like this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Cron task or set a task queue with a specific ETA

Comment: Thanks for the repky! Just one thing, can we use cron and/or task queues to perform these operations at regular intervals AS LONG AS the app remains hosted on the internet? Or can we only tell them to perform these a fixed number of times?

Answer (score 0):

As @PanoJee stated Cron is what your looking for.  Take a look at [Python Cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) it has all the information you need.